# SQL Select all MIN Values for each group

Tags: sql

So I need to select all the students, having the minimum grade for each prof. For example, if Augustinus had two students with grade 1.0, then I would like to see both in the result.

[Table of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnwT9.png)

[What the result could look like, if the LIMIT was set to 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dXRe.png)

So what I basically want is to see the best students that each prof has.

What I have tried is the following:

```
SELECT professor, student, min(note)
FROM temp
GROUP BY professor
ORDER BY note
```

The problem of course being that I only get one minimum value for each prof and not all minimum values.

*temp is just the table name

Comment: Posting pictures is frowned upon by most stackoverflow user's.

Comment: oh, ok. its just a bit much data for a manual handwritten table

Comment: @Carngo Have you tried any sql to get the desired results. If you post what you have tried then perhaps someone could point out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution myself:

```
SELECT professor, student, note
FROM temp
WHERE (professor, note) IN
    (SELECT professor, min(note)
    FROM temp
    GROUP BY professor
    ORDER BY note)
ORDER BY note, professor, student
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Won't that only limit you to the 10 overall student scores? In your question, it sounded like you wanted the 10 from each prof.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve these types of problems is to use a subquery to rank the grades for each class in a descending order. This involves a window function. With a second query you can limit the results based on your criteria of 10.

```
SELECT professor, student, note
FROM
(
    SELECT professor,student,note,
    row_number() over(partition by professor order by note desc) as downwardrank
) as rankings
WHERE
    downwardrank <= 10
```

Comment: Thank you! I Actually also found a solution.